# How to eliminate sequential sections in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I've got a sequential section within my kernel that is really slowing it down. However, I don't see how I could get rid of the inner loop. Any suggestions here?

```
__global__ void myKernel( int keep, int inc, int width, int* d_Xnum,
 int* d_Xco, bool* d_Xvalid,int* d_A )
{
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  int k1;

  if( i < keep && j <= i){
    int counter = 0;

    for(k1 = 0; k1 < inc; k1++){
      if(d_Xvalid[j*inc + k1] == 0)
         counter += (d_Xvalid[i*inc + d_Xco[j*width + k1]]);
    }

    d_A[i*keep+j] = inc - d_Xnum[i] - counter;
  }
}
```

I believe that eliminating `k1` will speed up my code by a good factor. However I don't see how to do it with `counter` being used. Any suggestions, ideas, thoughts would be more than welcome! 
This kernel is called:

```
         ...
  int t = 32;
  int b = keep/(32)+1;
  int b2 = (inc/32)+1;
  dim3 thread (t, t);
  dim3 block (b, inc);

  // kernel call
  myKernel<<<block, thread>>>(k, inc, width, d_Xnum,
                  d_Xco, d_Xvalid, d_A);
  cudaThreadSynchronize();
            ...
```

`keep` is around 9000 and `inc` around 20000

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what this code is actually suppose to be doing because it really is pretty obscure as written. Also would be good if you fix the syntax errors.

Comment: The short answer is to *maybe* use a parallel reduction. But the triangular structure of the if statement may make this difficult. Plus, you may have plenty of parallelism without parallelizing the counter sum (hard to say without knowing your block and grid dimensions, and GPU model), which means it would not give you any speedup. So to echo @talonmies, it's pretty hard to answer this question without more information.

Comment: It won't be easy to understand what the code is doing. Its very complex.I was looking for some kind of hint that would help me to speed up this piece of code, but I think it won't be easy without changing lots of sections of the entire code.

Comment: @Manolete: How can you seriously expect optimisation tips on a piece of code when you can't or won't explain what it is supposed be doing. It is clear from recent questions that you have a fairly limited understanding of the CUDA programming model, and with that as a background, it isn't obvious what features of that kernel are the real design pattern and what might be unnecessary or errors on your behalf. This could have been a good and useful stack overflow question, but it didn't turn out that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but it's something that probably can optimize your code and maybe help you to implement a parallel reduction for `k1` sum because you get rid of `if( i < keep && j <= i)`. There are other optimizations you could implement depending on your gpu model, like using textures to access those read-only vectors.

Because of the way you generate the indices many threads are stopped waiting for the others to finish. You are launching `keep*inc` threads but only a maximum number of `keep*(keep+1)/2` are actually doing something (because of the condition `j <= i`).

I think you can make it better with the following changes:

1. launch `keep*(keep+1)/2` threads
2. do the following to your code

   ```
   __global__ void myKernel( int keep, int inc, int width, int* d_Xnum,
   int* d_Xco, bool* d_Xvalid,int* d_A )
   {
     int k = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
     int i = (int)(sqrt(0.25+2.0*k)-0.5); 
     int j = k - i*(i+1)/2;

     int k1;
     if( i < keep && j < inc){
       int counter = 0;

       for(k1 = 0; k1 < inc; k1++){
         if(d_Xvalid[j*inc + k1] == 0)
            counter += (d_Xvalid[i*inc + d_Xco[j*width + k1]]);
       }

       d_A[i*keep+j] = inc - d_Xnum[i] - counter;
     }
   }
   ```

What you're doing (for `keep = 4` launch `4*4 = 16` threads, in the best case scenario. If `inc > keep`, as it seems to be the case, you're launching even more threads) can be seen as (each 'box' is a thread)

```
_________________________________
| i = 0 | i = 0 | i = 0 | i = 0 |
| j = 0 |   -   |   -   |   -   |
_________________________________
| i = 1 | i = 1 | i = 1 | i = 1 |
| j = 0 | j = 1 |   -   |   -   |
_________________________________
| i = 2 | i = 2 | i = 2 | i = 2 |
| j = 0 | j = 1 | j = 2 |   -   |
_________________________________
| i = 3 | i = 3 | i = 3 | i = 3 |
| j = 0 | j = 1 | j = 2 | j = 3 |
_________________________________
```

I propose you add an index `k` and generate `i` and `j` from it according to your needs (for `keep = 4` launch `(4*(4+1)/2 = 10` threads)

```
_________________________________________________________________________________
| k = 0 | k = 0 | k = 1 | k = 0 | k = 1 | k = 2 | k = 0 | k = 1 | k = 2 | k = 3 |
| i = 0 | i = 1 | i = 1 | i = 2 | i = 2 | i = 2 | i = 3 | i = 3 | i = 3 | i = 3 |
| j = 0 | j = 0 | j = 1 | j = 0 | j = 1 | j = 2 | j = 0 | j = 1 | j = 2 | j = 3 |
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

this can be done with

- `i = (int)(sqrt(0.25+2*k)-0.5)`
- `j = k - i*(i+1)/2`

You can accept this as a recipe or look a little bit on the mathematics behind it.

To get here you know that for `j = 0` you have `i*(i+1)/2 = k` (because k = [0+1+2+...+i = i*(i+1)/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%80%A6) ). Now, if you solve this equation you get the equation for `i` (the cast for int rounds down and ensures that it gets the right result when `j!=0` too).
To get `j` you should subtract to `k` the value it would have if `j` was 0: `i*(i+1)/2`.

Comment: @ JeanMoniuc: awesome reply! Let me try if it works and if it speeds up a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @ JeanMoniuc :it really speeds up the code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I am doing something wrong here. I am launching the kernel with :`myKernel<<<((keep*(keep+1)/2)/128)+1, 128>>>(...)`

Comment: Done! It is very clever mathematically speaking, but I don't understand why launching more threads it slows than the code...

Comment: @Manolete: Is it already working? The threads are sent to gpu in warps (currently each warp has 32 threads). When you have threads that aren't doing anything they still have to wait that for the threads in their warp to finish, occupying the place of threads that could be calculating what you want. Most of the times (though not always) many inactive threads mean slower code

Comment: @ JeanMoniuc: It works, but from time to time it gives the wrong result. Are we missing something here? I have debug it for small numbers and it works okay, but I don't see why it fails randomly...

Comment: @ JeanMoniuc: `keep  = 10000`, so that means that 50m threads. If i choose a number of threads larger than 512, it takes an awful amount of time. Hoever if I choose a number smaller than 512 it is really fast but I do not get the right answer all the time. Why is that? Is it related with the number of blocks and threads that a GPU can launch? May fail if number of `blocks > 65525` ?? Depends on the day of the GPU or what?

Comment: @Manolete yeah, unless you have a 3.0 device you'll find problems working with big keep restrict to 1 dimensional grid and blocks. I'll put an example [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53885383/nnp1.cu) so you can see how to use 2 dimensional blocks to do your calculations. If you need keep values much bigger than that ask me and I can write it in 3 dimensions (if your gpu supports it). However expect it to take 'awful' amounts of time since the computational time grows approximately quadratically in keep, so keep=10000 takes about 400 times the time to keep=512...

Comment: @Manolete I noted now that you added the block and grid size you were using. So the code I gave you works only if `keep < inc`. If you do `keep > inc` then you should include a `j <= inc` condition. I'll edit my answer to include this situation